# Organizing Different Versions of App in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, dependency-management

I'm developing an iPhone app that can edit images. Ultimately, I want to have a small version that allows the user to simply edit their images, and a large version that allows social networking of the images. Then I'd like to develop a version of each for the iPad.

Being that this is my first foray into commercial mobile development, I'm confused about how to organize all these versions in Xcode. Obviously, there will be file reuse shared between each version. I guess my question is, how do I go about organizing these separate projects in the most efficient way so that they share files and so when I edit a particular file that is shared, the changes are made to each version of the application? Is there some kind of construct to follow in XCode?

Are there any links or literature on how to go about doing this? (was not sure the correct term to search for it).

Comment: http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/

Comment: @ACB the linked approach is not very good. one would have to manage each file (e.g. source, resource) for each app. there's a ton of tedium (and thus room for error) in doing so. see my answer for an approach which avoids that problem.

Comment: @justin, Not sure about that. In the past I have used it that way and i didnt have any issues. All I need to do was switch the schema and build to get different apps.

Comment: @ACB i'll restate that - it's **bad** :) duplicating your work should be minimized (or eliminated wherever possible).

Comment: Thanks for the link ACB. @Justin - are you referring to the fact that the guy in the link is copying the files into the second target.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider yes. I haven't mentioned it specifically: that (linked) approach also creates redundant  work for the tool chain , resulting in longer builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember: If you find yourself repeating/duplicating something, suspect that you're doing it wrong.

Your Xcode project will have 4 targets in this scenario. The basic target layout for this setup looks like this:

- A Static Library (for your shared source files)
- A Resource Bundle (for your shared resources)
- App-Full (Universal)
- App-Lite (Universal)

The apps link to the shared static library, and copy the resource bundle.

Naturally, apps will have sources/libraries/dependencies which differ -- those go in the app target (or some other dependency).

Given your background: Plan on it taking a good amount of time (initially and as you go) and patience to figure out how these dependencies should be composed, used, and maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the "lite" and "full" projects separate but within the same workspace. That way you can keep the shared files in one project and simply use a shared reference to them in the other. All changes made to the shared files from either project will affect both.

As far as iPhone/iPad versions, I would also suggest that you keep these apps completely separate but within the same workspace (so that they can share code) as well. If you look around about the suggestions for managing both apps in a single project (aka, universal app), the only real benefit is that customers can buy one app and can download it on either device and some may get upset if that isn't available to them. If your app is free, don't worry about it.

Lastly, a caveat about workspaces, you need to uniquely name your files across all projects. For example if you're working with a project that uses a MainViewController.h subclass and another project that uses a MainViewController.h subclass, you could assign or edit the wrong one by accident regardless of what project you're in, so be wary. If using unique file names is a problem, you can bypass using workspaces by simply creating an empty project to dump all of your shared code into and then add references to your standalone apps from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to keep various copies of your project for different functionality, it will be eventually confusing, as there are places when XCode offers you one thing instead of another. One such place is - when you open a project from location X, it will also show you your copy from location Y since you opened it last time. As a result, you are likely to commit more mistakes. Organizer is one more such place where you can make mistakes.

XCode is self-contained enough to maintain both iPhone and iPad versions. You will have two separate storyboards which can be made part of one project if you chose universal as the type of app.

As for various features, you shouldn't be maintaining separate copies of your project. Instead, recommended way is to keep all features within single project, and have app logic provide access to various features.

XCode keeps version of your build under Targets section when you click project. To maintain multiple versions through your dev cycle, use source code repository (git or svn).

Comment: I still recommend against universal, the iPad is different enough where you would develop almost completely different view hierarchy, embedding stackable split views instead of navigationcontrollers, popouts instead of additional view controllers, etc that even building a separate storyboard would not be enough to turn your base code base into a hairy mess. Granted, this does depend on the app, but in my experience I would only build a universal app if I didn't care about the quality of my iPad version.