# Importing an existing project to another project in iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, storyboard

I have in one of my projects a function that applies effects to a picture. Now, I want to use the same functionality in another project. I just like to ask if how importing works in iOS. Also, in addition to the backend functions, I want to use the similar view. I implemented it using storyboards.

Any insights will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277464/organizing-different-versions-of-app-in-xcode/13278353#13278353

Comment: I am told that CocoPods is the way to do this, but I haven't tried it yet.